# A property of e?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Define $f(n) = \lfloor {ne}\rfloor$ if $n$ is odd and $f(n) = \lfloor {n/e}\rfloor$ if $n$ is even.  Is the set $\{n, f(n), f(f(n)),\dots\}$ bounded for every $n$?

Computer sampling suggests that each such set is finite - indeed, that the iterates reach 0 - but that the set of cardinalities of the sets is infinite.

Comment: just curious: how far ($n$-wise) did you test? How much precision for $e$ did you use?

Comment: It should be noted that Clark asked a question about these sequences when $e$ is replaced by an arbitrary real numbers: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/204764/which-irrationals-yield-bounded-sets-of-iterates Not that that makes the current question uninteresting, but I thought it would be useful to provide a link.

Comment: Yaakov - Mathematica checked for $n$ up $50000$ using    "MaxExtraPrecision = Infinity".  Here's the set for $n=5$: ${5,13,35,95,258,94,34,12,4,1,2,0}$

Answer (score 5):

Write the iteration as $x(j+1) = f(x(j))$ with $x(0) = n$.
Heuristically, while $x(j)$ is large, $\log x(j)$ undergoes a "random walk" with 
a slight bias to the left; with probability $1$ you eventually get to a small enough value of $x(j)$, and then you're trapped in a fixed point or cycle.
This heuristic should not be taken too seriously, but it does suggest that the set should always be finite, although sometimes very large.

Comment: See my answer at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/204764/which-irrationals-yield-bounded-sets-of-iterates for an example where the euristic won't always do.